# Possibility of a Runtime exception during HttpClient connection manager shutdown?

Tags: java, apache, http, httpclient

I have a Java process where I use an `HttpClient` along with a `PoolingClientConnectionManager` to copy files between `CouchDB` databases using multiple execution threads.

The code is something like this:

```
private boolean copyDocuments(JsonArray docs) {

        PoolingClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
        clientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(50);
        clientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager);

        //Fixed thread pool initialized using ExecutorService
       try{
          //iterate documents and create runnable threads for each document using the executor service. Each thread will use the same httpClient instance with a local HttpContext
       }
        ...
       } finally {
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
       }
```

My concern is if there could be any `Runtime exceptions` when I do the connection manager shutdown in the finally block and if it is, whether I should handle it.

Comment: IMHO, the major question is: How would you handle it?

Comment: @jokster the internal implementation of shutdown handles IOExceptions which is thrown by the method below it. So I am wondering if it is really necessary for me to add any further handling within my code.

Comment: Unless you know exactly what to do with the exception, I wouldn't add any further exception handling.